# Preencher corpo de email com intervalo de celulas Planilha Google

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal,
Estou com dificuldade em como colocar neste código um intervalo entre células como por exemplo "A3:B18" no corpo do email.

O script em si esta funcionando tranquilo, somente este intervalo que não sei como fazer.

```
// Envio de e-mail
function EnviarEmail() {

// Variáveis
var vplan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var vparamail = "";
var vmsgmail = "";
var vassunto = "";

//Varre a lista de e-mails
//for (var i = 2; i < (vtotal+2); ++i){

//Recupera os valores
vparamail = vplan.getRange("B1").getValue();
vmsgmail = vplan.getRange("A4").getValue();
vplan.getRange("A4:B18").getValue();
vassunto = vplan.getRange("B2").getValue();



// Envia o e-mail  
MailApp.sendEmail(vparamail, vassunto, vmsgmail);

Browser.msgBox('Email Enviado');

};
```